# Is it still correct to say "This doll comes with her own dress" when you bought it 2 days, 2 weeks, 2 months or 2 years ago?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, tense, present-simple

In the [dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/come),

> 7 BE PRODUCED/SOLD [always + adverb/preposition] to be produced or
> sold with particular features
>
> come in
>
> This particular sofa comes in four different colours.
>
> Cats come in many shapes and sizes.
>
> come with
>
> The computer comes complete with software and games.

It says "[This cuddly baby doll comes with her own blanket and bottle.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come)".

I guess at the time the speaker said that sentence, he already bought that "**cuddly baby doll**" before.

But the speaker still uses the simple present tense here "**comes with**".

Now, the question is:

**Can he say that sentence when he bought it 2 days ago, 2 weeks ago, 2 months ago or 2 years ago?**

Is the fact "**This doll comes with her own dress**" a permanent fact no matter when he bought it?

Answer (score 1):

He can say that, assuming he knows that it is still the case.

No matter how long it is since he purchased his doll, if it is still being sold with the same accessories, the present tense is correct.

If he knew is was no longer available, he should say:

*"This cuddly baby doll came with her own blanket and bottle."*

Added after comment by Kate Bunting.

Unless you were advising someone about buying a similar doll now, you would tend to use the past tense

Comment: How do we know that the factory no longer produces that kind of doll?

Comment: You would use the version that apples to what you *believe* the situation to be. You might know, or you might make a guess.

Comment: If he bought one for his child two years ago he would say that it 'came with' the accessories - unless he is advising someone else about buying a similar doll now.